# Disable Undo Delete/Move/Rename/Copy menu

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn

I install TortoiseSVN. It add "update" menu item to right click menu. And this menu item 's 
hotkey is "u". Unfortunately, the "undo XXX" menu item 's hotkey is "u", too.

Sometimes I right click on the desktop or inside a folder and press "u". It will trigger the "undo XXX" menu item when this menu item is enable, but I want to trigger "update" menu item. It's a great inconvenience to me.

How can I disable the "undo XXX" menu item, or change the hotkey of the "undo XXX" menu item, or fix it?

Comment: try [this](http://www.onlinehowto.net/enabling-and-disabling-tortoisesvn-items-in-the-right-click-menu-in-windows/1445) or [this](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_id/tsvn-admins-disablemenus.html)

Comment: Hi, sergmat. I want to disable "undo XXX" menu item, not TortoiseSVN menu. Are you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the accelerators on the context menu.
It's in the [advanced settings page](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-registry). Look for `ShellMenuAccelerators`.

Comment: Hi, Stefan. I want to save accelerators of SVN, and do not need "undo XXX" menu item's hotkey. Are you have any idea?